# Change entire row colour, not just cell

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have the following code in xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="DgAlarmsGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,29,5,10"  
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="0.517,0.861" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <pagingDemo:ValueColorConverter x:Key="Colorconverter"/>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Column.DisplayIndex}" Value="10">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.Text, Converter={StaticResource Colorconverter}}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

And this class:

```
public class ValueColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    var str = value as string;
    if (str == null) return null;
    int intValue;
    if (!int.TryParse(str, out intValue)) return null;
    if (intValue < 0) return (MainWindow.AlarmColours[256]);
    return (intValue > 255) ? null : (MainWindow.AlarmColours[intValue]);
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

This colours the background of the cell correctly depending on its value. But I need to colour the entire row, but I cannot get this to work. If I change CellStyle to RowStyle and TargetType to DataGridRow, then it doesn't colour any cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you are trying to set the color of the row depending on the value present in some column.

The reason why it is not working for DataGridRow is it does not contain Column.DisplayIndex property.

You may like to try the following.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=yourPropertyName, Converter={StaticResource vjColorConverter}}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Instead of trying to read the Value from the column's content, directly get it from the DataContext itself. DataContext is the one to which your DataGrid is bound to fill the rows. For your case it is the property name of the 11th Display Column.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't know where I declare ShouldColor. I only started looking at WPF this morning and need to read more about it.

Comment: Edited to remove the not needed DataTrigger.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I have now created this in WinForms (much easier for me!). I thought I had picked an easy project to start learning WPF, but it's too alien to me. I really need to get a book on it. Thanks for your help. I have marked your answer as the answer anyway.